# IE BHO: SAP Netweaver portal page doesnt trigger any browser events

Tags: c#-4.0, bho, mshtml, netweaver

Im trying to create a BHO for a SAP Netweaver portal webgui and I have no idea on how SAP Netweaver works. The user selects an option from a combo box and that opens up another web form.

The user fills up the form and presses "Enter" and that kinda does a post back, validates the data entered by the user and shows an error img next to the fields with invalid data. Also an error message is shown in a status bar kinda div in the bottom of the page.

The BHO is suppose to capture these error text and launch another windows application.

But none of the browser events (BeforeNavigate2, DocumentComplete, NavigateComplete2) gets fired when the user presses the Enter button due to which I couldnt read the DOM of that page.

Any idea on how to trigger the browser events in this scenario?

Comment: If your BHO works, it should at least see some events when you first navigate to the page. Is that ok?

Comment: yes, When the page loads first, I get all the events. The events don't fire only when I fill the form and press Enter button.

Comment: Then, it's maybe some Ajax nightmare. See if you can inspect the main frame content on each "DownloadComplete" (if they trigger). Else: polling :-( Or script injection and/or monitoring the "button"